# SQL - Group Values by Percentile/Merge Rankings

Tags: sql, t-sql, ranking, scoring

I have multiple tables that contain the name of a company/attribute and a ranking.

[image]

I would like to write a piece of code which allows a range of Scores to be placed into specific Groups based on the percentile of the score in relationship to tables Score total. I provided a very easy use case to demonstrate what I am looking for, splitting a group of 10 companies into 5 groups, but I would like to scales this in order to apply the 5 groups to data sets with many rows WITHOUT having to specify values in a CASE statement.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NTILE(5) OVER(ORDER BY score)` might actually put rows with the same value into different quantiles (This is probably not what you want, at least I never liked that).

It's quite similar to

```
5 * (row_number() over (order by score) - 1) / count(*) over ()
```

but if the number of rows can't be evenly divided the remainder rows are added to the first quantiles when using `NTILE` and randomly for `ROW_NUMBER`.

To assign all the rows with the same value to the same quantile you need to do your own calculation:

```
5 * (rank() over (order by score) - 1) / count(*) over ()
```

Comment: tried this out and there is one distinct difference from vkp's suggestion. In vkp's suggestion the groups are 1 -5, in your suggestion the groups are 0 -4 ... Is there any way to reproduce your method with groups 1 - 5 instead of 0 - 4?

Comment: Adding `+1` to the result?

Comment: `5 * (rank() over (order by [Account Score]) + 1) / count(*) over () as grp2` gives me 0 - 5, only two items out of 7000  are a 5 ... maybe i am just misunderstanding the solution

Comment: `5 * (rank() over (order by score) - 1) / count(*) over () + 1`

Comment: For anyone seeing this solution using a version of SQL that does not do integer division with "/", for example HIVE, you can use DIV to do integer division as follows: 10*(RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score) - 1) / COUNT(*) OVER () + 1 AS decile

Answer (score 7):

You can use `NTILE` to divide the data into 5 buckets based on score. However, if the data can't be divided into equal number of bins or if there are ties, one of the groups will have more members.

```
SELECT t.*, NTILE(5) OVER(ORDER BY score) as grp
FROM tablename t
```

[Read more about NTILE here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx)

Comment: Or if there are ties, then the `NTILE()` bins won't be the same size.

Comment: included it in the answer @GordonLinoff

Comment: `NTILE` might actually put rows with the same value into different quantiles. If you don't want that you can use this calculation:  `5 *  (rank()  over (order by score) - 1) / count(*) over ()`

Comment: @dnoeth .. you should post it as an answer

Comment: Just used NTILE that @vkp suggested and it seems to work. However I may be overlooking some of the issues that were mentioned. Is there a preference between vkp answer and dnoeth ?

Comment: @hansolo: I added an answer (as suggested by vkp), preference should be based on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `ROW_NUMBER()` and [`CEILING()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx) :

```
SELECT t.name,t.score,
       CEILING(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.score)/2) as group
FROM YourTable t
```

This will divide each group of two into a single group, using the `ROW_NUMBER()` result .

Comment: Biut then you need to know about the number of rows in the result to be able to create n quantiles.